# Error while Running Haproxy and Apache on same server for load balancing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, haproxy

Let Me describe the scenrio:

I have two servers , i.e server1 and server2 and running apache on both .
I have installed haproxy on server1 and configured like :

`global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon`


`defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http`


`frontend localnodes
    bind *:80
    mode http
    default_backend nodes`


`backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server web01 IP1:80 check
    server web02 IP2:80 check`


`listen stats *:1936
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats hide-version
    stats auth username:password`

While running haproxy (service haproxy restart) , I am getting following error:

### Starting frontend localnodes: cannot bind socket

I tried to change the apache default port to 81 to , also I tried to 
change sysctl.conf , net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1 ... 
Still getting same error .  I am very new to server configuration , 
can any one help ?

Comment: Ports above 1023 do work? I guess you start it manually? If that is the case, set up a proper initscript/unit-file.

Answer (score 0):

If ports are free (check with netstat -punta | grep 80) start the service with user root.
Change "user haproxy" and "group haproxy" to "user root" and "group root"